# Hadoop configuration error (on Mac): Cannot set priority of namenode and secondarynamenode process xxxx

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, apple-silicon

I've been receiving these errors when start-dfs.sh.

Checked every hint that I could find – without success. Not sure if it has to do with the dfs.namenode.name.dir folder possibly not existing (how can I find out?) and/or wrong permissions (how can I find out?).

Using Hadoop 3.3.4 and Java 11.0.17
On Macbook Air M1 with Ventura 13.1

Here are my configurations:

**.bash_profile**
`export HADOOP_HOME=/Users/thi/hadoop-3.3.4`
`export HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME\`
`export HADOOP_COMMON_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME`
`export HADOOP_HDFS_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME`
`export YARN_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME`
`export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop`
`export YARN_CONF_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop`

`export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.17.jdk/Contents/Home`

`PATH=$HADOOP_HOME/bin/:$HADOOP_HOME/sbin/:$JAVA_HOME/bin/:$PATH`
`export PATH`

**core-site.xml**
`<configuration>`
`<property>`
`<name>fs.defaultFS</name>`
`<value>hdfs://Namenode:9000</value>`
`</property>`
`</configuration>`

**hadoop-env.sh**
`export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.17.jdk/Contents/Home`
`export HADOOP_HOME=/Users/thi/hadoop-3.3.4`
`export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/bin:$HADOOP_HOME/sbin`

**hdfs-site.xml**
`<configuration>`
`<property>`
`<name>dfs.replication</name>`
`<value>1</value>`
`</property>`
`</configuration>`

**mapred-site.xml**
`<configuration>`
`<property>`
`<name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>`
`<value>yarn</value>`
`</property>`
`</configuration>`

**yarn-site.xml**
`<configuration>`
`<property>`
`<name>yarn.resourcemanager.hostname</name>`
`<value>localhost</value>`
`</property>`
`<property>`
`<name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>`
`<value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>`
`</property>`
`</configuration>`

Comment: Use `hdfs namenode start` and `hdfs datanode start` separately

Comment: In Markdown you can format code blocks with three backticks - see https://www.markdownguide.org/extended-syntax/#fenced-code-blocks.

Comment: Thanks OneCricketeer for the suggestion. Unfortunately I'm receiving the same error as before when runnig ```hadoop-daemon.sh start namenode```

Comment: Thx Ben for the syntax hint